# Getting confused with C++ template

Tags: c++, templates, programming-languages, semantics

I am looking at some c++ code and do not understand the purpose of the template declaration in this situation:

```
template<> void operator>>(const ClassA& s, const ClassB d) {...}
```

What is the semantic of `template<>`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is, indeed, template specialization, as others before mentioned. There must be some previously declared function template, such as:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
void operator>>(const T& s, const U d) {...}
```

However, it is quite misguided. It is much better to remove the `template<>` altogether, so `operator>>` would just be overloaded. The problem with function template specialization is that it may lead to unexpected behaviour in the presence of overloaded functions (and `operator>>` has lots of overloads), since the specialization does not overload. This means that the compiler first selects the most appropriate overload for the function and then, if the selected overload is a function template, it looks for template specializations to see if there is an appropriate one.

A classical example (unfortunately, I don't remember where I read it). Consider this overloaded function template:

```
template <typename T>
void Function(T param);

template <typename T>
void Function(T* param);

template <>
void Function(int* param);

main()
{
  int i = 5;
  Function(&i);
}
```

As expected, the template specialization for `int*` is called. But just change the order of the function definitions:

```
template <typename T>
void Function(T param);

template <>
void Function(int* param);

template <typename T>
void Function(T* param);

main()
{
  int i = 5;
  Function(&i);
}
```

Now the general template for `T*` is called, since we are specializing the template for `T`, not for `T*`, and this second template is better suited for our call. This would be avoided if we overloaded the function instead of specializing the template:

```
void Function(int* param);
```

Now the order of declaration does not matter, we will always call the overload for `int*`.

UPDATE: Now I know who to credit. I read about this in an [article](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm) by Herb Sutter. The example was provided by Peter Dimov and Dave Abrahams.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, so this is yet an other trick that complicate the language. Like overload I don't think that this is a good idea see: http://gbracha.blogspot.com/2009/09/systemic-overload.html

Comment: @mathk: I disagree with most ideas in the article you link.

Comment: you disagree with one of th guy that design Java. What do you dislike?

Comment: @mathk: He seems to disagree with himself too, because Java allows all these things he critisizes (such as constructors and function overloading).

Comment: that put him in the right spot to really know why it is not a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

It is a [*template specialization*](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html#faq-35.7): (fully or partially) resolving the template for a specific type. (Your particular example seems to be a full specialization, as no more template parameters are left unresolved in it. If the template has multiple parameters, and you specialize only some of them, it is called *partial template specialization*)

This allows one to provide type-specific optimizations for a given template, or to do many clever tricks such as detecting the static type of variables etc.

Comment: éter I don't think the example presented by the OP is valid. If I recall correctly, you can't specialize a function, you have to overload it. Specialization only works for classes.

Comment: @Victor, template functions do have some limitations compared to class templates; dunno how (and whether is) this changed C++03 and later though. However, the linked examples in C++ FAQ seem to be function template specializations so I presume it should work :-)

Comment: éter hmm interesting, I just tried it on a few compilers and it does indeed accept the code. It looks like partial specialization doesn't work on function however. That must be what I was thinking of.

Comment: @Victor T: That's it, partial function template specialization is invalid, but full specialization is accepted. Nevertheless, specializing a function template is seldom a good idea (I have tried to explain that in my answer).

Comment: @Victor: Partial specialization isn't available for functions in C++03, but full specialization is fine.

Answer (score 2):

This is [Template specialization](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/template_specialization.html)

Answer (score 2):

You use this syntax when you want to provide a *special* handler for a particular template type. Consider:

```
// A normal template definition.
template <typename AType>
whoami () {   std::cout << "I am an unknown type.";  }

// Now we specialize.
template <>
whoami<int> () {   std::cout << "I am an integer!";  }
```

There's some other nonsense involved, particularly "partial specialization", but that's the basic function of `template <>`.